# How to start K3s server after running k3s-killall.sh script

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service, k3s, kubernetes-apiserver

I was having K3s cluster with below pods running:

```
kube-system   pod/calico-node-xxxx                          
kube-system   pod/calico-kube-controllers-xxxxxx   
kube-system   pod/metrics-server-xxxxx
kube-system   pod/local-path-provisioner-xxxxx
kube-system   pod/coredns-xxxxx
xyz-system    pod/some-app-xxx
xyz-system    pod/some-app-db-xxx
```

I want to stop all of the K3s pods & reset the containerd state, so I used [/usr/local/bin/k3s-killall.sh](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/upgrades/killall/) script and all pods got stopped (at least I was not able to see anything in `watch kubectl get all -A` except `The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?` message)

Can someone tell me how to start the k3s server up because now after firing `kubectl get all -A` I am getting message `The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

**PS:**

- When I ran `k3s server` command, for fraction of seconds I can see the same above pods(with same pod ids) that I mentioned while the command is running. After few seconds, command get exited and again same message `The connection to the...` start displaying.

Does this means that `k3s-killall.sh` have not deleted my pods as it is showing the same pods with same ids ( like `pod/some-app-xxx` ) ?

Comment: As far as i know k3s uses an embedded etcd service. The etcd is keeping the state of your cluster. This includes deployments, statefulset and every other resources. To my surprise i cannot say why it's failing. Probably you could check your logs or use systemctl status k3s. Not sure, what k3s-killall.sh is actually doing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. I think you need to restart K3s via systemd if you want your cluster back after kill. Try command:  
   `sudo systemctl restart k3s`
   This is supported by the installation script for systemd and openrc. Refer [rancher doc](https://www.rancher.co.jp/docs/k3s/latest/en/running/)
2. The pod-xxx id will remain same as k3s-killall.sh doesn't uninstall k3s (you can verify this, after k3s-killall script `k3s -v` will return output) and it only restart the pods with same image. The `Restarts` column will increase the count of all pods.

Comment: "sudo systemctl restart k3s" command does not have any effect. The age parameter has the same value for pods,svc and ingress components. I wanted to skip traefik server and restart k3s

Answer (score -2):

cd /usr/local/bin

> Blockquote

./k3s server